# $HOME in Git Bash and VS Code are different

Tags: git, bash, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to change the HOME of my Git Bash. I did so successfully by adding "HOME='/path/to/desired/dir'" to the profile file in /etc, but it is only changed for Git Bash running externally. The Git Bash terminal in VS Code still has the old folder as the HOME. [Here is echo $HOME in both.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf2zS.png) My VS Code terminal setting is: "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe". Any ideas?

Comment: It seems git-bash and VS Code have their own git-bash.exe. Run VS Code's git-bash.exe and add "HOME" to its profile.

Comment: @ElpieKay I don't know what happened, but it resolved itself... So odd. When I first open the VS Code terminal, it is the old path, but using the `cd` command, it goes to the HOME path and it is the one I set it to. Thanks for you response.

Comment: Looks like you haven't executed the .bash_profile after making changes. Note that just changing values inside the profile will not reflect outside until the file is executed.